# I am getting an error while running Angular Application

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

I installed bootstrap command using Angular cli , for some time my Application was working while I was developing my Application 
But After some time I am getting this error mentioned below

NOTE : Just wanted to inform you that I looked into the node_module file , bootstrap.min.css file exists there but again I am getting the error

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ../node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/A4/node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo'
```

Comment: Did you declare this CSS file as a project asset in your `angular[-cli].json` file ?

Comment: yes I have already done that

"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],

Comment: Did you change your project folder structure and added a `demo` folder? The error says the bootstrap css location is wrong. If you did change folder structure, fix bootstrap.min.css location in .angular.json would fix the problem.

Comment: It worked .. thanks